# Issue with floating buttons right of my to do list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a to-do list app with jquery or bootstrap. Just css grid and vanilla js.

I'm currently having an issue floating my 'delete' buttons of list items to the right. The first one floats all the way right white the others kind of stagger.

[image]

Below is my code:

```js
var addItemButton = document.getElementById('addItem')
var onEnter = document.getElementById('newNote')


//below event listener adds an item to the list on click
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let item = document.getElementById('newNote').value
  let node = document.createElement("LI")
  let textnode = document.createTextNode(item)

  node.appendChild(textnode)
  if (item) {
    document.getElementById('list-body').appendChild(node)
  }


  let node2 = document.createElement('BUTTON')
  let textnode2 = document.createTextNode('Delete')
  node2.appendChild(textnode2)
  node.appendChild(node2)

  node2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    node2.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(node)

  });

  document.getElementById('newNote').value = ''
});


onEnter.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    addItemButton.click();
  }
})


function applyButton() { //onload for dummy data or data from db
  let getListObjects = document.querySelectorAll("li")

  for (let i = 0; i < getListObjects.length; i++) {

    let node2 = document.createElement('BUTTON')
    let textnode2 = document.createTextNode('Delete')
    node2.appendChild(textnode2)

    getListObjects[i].appendChild(node2)

    let y = getListObjects[i].querySelector('button')
    y.addEventListener('click', function() {
      y.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(getListObjects[i])
    });

  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#main-grid {
  grid-column: 2;
}

#newNote {
  height: 25px;
}

#inputIdForGrid {
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#addItem {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: right;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li:nth-child(2n+0) {
  background-color: grey;
}

li>button {
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<body onload="applyButton()">

  <h1>Vanilla JS ToDo List - No Jquery, No Bootstrap</h1>


  <div class='container'>
    <div id='main-grid'>
      <div class="container2">
        <div id='inputIdForGrid'><input type='text' placeholder="Enter 
     List Items Here" id='newNote'> </div>
        <div> <a href='#'><i  class="fas fa-plus-circle" id='addItem' 
     type='submit' ></i></a></div>
      </div>

      <ul id='list-body'>

        <li>Walk Dog</li>
        <li>Buy Apples</li>
        <li>Hit Gym and Lift Bro</li>
        <li>Stretch</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I really am unsure how to solve this issue currently, I've never faced this problem before.

Comment: You could use flex instead of grid for better results in this case. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Cat you know what happened, the marggin property I had set was causing it. I just changed it to margin-top only. It works as intended now.

GOnna take a look at that flexbox example though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
button {
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has something to do with the button margin.
The margin (10px) is bigger than the row so it will push the bottom buttons to the left.
Just change the `margin: 10px;` to `margin: 7px 10px 7px 10px;`

```css
button {
    margin: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox on parent element and justify-content: flex-end.