# Issue with ToDO list app and list item length

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Q/A bare bones todolist app and notice that when a list item that is really long is added to the list, it pushes the button out.

Is there a way I can make the LI element larger when the textnode hits the button margin instead of pushing the button out of the LI element. Below is a screenshot. I'll post my source code below, but maybe this is a question that is a quick fix?

[image]

My source code can be found here - [Issue with floating buttons right of my to do list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079045/issue-with-floating-buttons-right-of-my-to-do-list/55079292#55079292)

Comment: Just make your text overflow within the width, so button stays in the same place

Comment: use a different approach like making two different sections of a larger div, one left section for text that can be of any size and other section for the button. This will be neater and will not hide any text even after large text.

Comment: @AvinashKarhana i may need to change the way i assign buttons to the li then. The buttons are children of the LI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) If I understood you well, you can easily fix it with CSS-Grid:

```
li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 100px;
  grid-template-areas: 'text button';
}

li > span {
  grid-area: text;
}

li > button {
  grid-area: button;
  height: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/axqwhj29/

Play with the example linked above resizing the result area to check if that's what you are looking for.

B) Also, but I don't recommend you, if you really don't wanna change your `li` hight and you have a maximum text width (ex: 25 characters), you can clip parts of your message in a phone vertical view and if the user flips to horizontal show the whole text automatically.

https://jsfiddle.net/qfy3mz01/

Hope this help :)

Comment: the man, the myth, the legend, no the god, gengns. Lol but seriously this was exactly what I was talking about. I'm new to grid so still unsure of somethings. I'll play around with it. I jsut looked into template areas

Comment: hahaha. Lol, I'm so glad that my code helped you noobcoderiam ^^ Please, could you click on 'This answer is useful' above to help others in the future or/and mark as resolved :) CSS Grid is powerful and really easy check out this: https://youtu.be/7kVeCqQCxlk

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have wrapped the text inside the `li` with `span` element and and added I add grid display to `li` and give every element inside the `li` a `width` and then I have added `word-break: break-word;` so the line will break when the text of the `span` reach the width limit and don't affect the delete `button` and I've deleted `height` from `li` so the `li` will grow with the lines on it

```js
var addItemButton = document.getElementById('addItem')
var onEnter = document.getElementById('newNote')


//below event listener adds an item to the list on click
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let item = document.getElementById('newNote').value
  let node = document.createElement("li")
  let span = document.createElement("span")
  let textnode = document.createTextNode(item)

  span.appendChild(textnode)
  node.appendChild(span)
  if (item) {
    document.getElementById('list-body').appendChild(node)
  }


  let node2 = document.createElement('BUTTON')
  let textnode2 = document.createTextNode('Delete')
  node2.appendChild(textnode2)
  node.appendChild(node2)

  node2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    node2.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(node)
  });

  document.getElementById('newNote').value = ''
});


onEnter.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    addItemButton.click();
  }
})


function applyButton() { //onload for dummy data or data from db
  let getListObjects = document.querySelectorAll("li")

  for (let i = 0; i < getListObjects.length; i++) {

    let node2 = document.createElement('BUTTON')
    let textnode2 = document.createTextNode('Delete')
    node2.appendChild(textnode2)

    getListObjects[i].appendChild(node2)

    let y = getListObjects[i].querySelector('button')
    y.addEventListener('click', function() {
      y.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(getListObjects[i])
    });

  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#main-grid {
  width: 100%;
}

#newNote {
  height: 25px;
}

#inputIdForGrid {
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
}

#addItem {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: right;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2.5fr .5fr;
}

span {
  word-break: break-word;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: grey;
}

li>button {
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<body onload="applyButton()">
  <h1>Vanilla JS ToDo List - No Jquery, No Bootstrap</h1>
  <div class='container'>
    <div id='main-grid'>
      <div class="container2">
        <div id='inputIdForGrid'>
          <input type='text' placeholder="Enter List Items Here" id='newNote'>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href='#' id="addItem">Hi</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul id='list-body'>
        <li><span>run all around town. walk all around town. drive all around town</span></li>
        <li><span>Buy Apples</span></li>
        <li><span>Hit Gym and Lift Bro</span></li>
        <li><span>Stretch</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

P.S. I've edited your js code so it will generate `span` and add the text inside it

Comment: ill take a look at everything you did and break it down to see how you made it all work. i appreaciate the response.

Comment: No problem I did nothing at all :)